# How can I remove a timestamp with text after it in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

Tried `\d` and such but I'm a new user to Notepad++

```
[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}] [Server thread/WARN]: Command Block chain tried to execute more than 0 steps!
```

Tried this currently but says it cannot find it.
Adding space yields the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `]` are characters in regex representing [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) so you must escape them to match a literal `[` or `]`

```
\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\] \[Server thread/WARN\]: Command Block chain tried to execute more than 0 steps!
```

Comment: You're a god! Thank you.